# How to save file content without modifying the space or indents

Tags: c#, file, io, text-indent

I am using the below code to read and update the `text` file.

```
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filepath))
    {
      var json = r.ReadToEnd();
      AppSettings rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(json);
      rootObject.Settings.Size = 20;
      output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject);
    }

    //Save back to the same file
    File.WriteAllText(filepath, output);
```

Before reading file content was looking like this

```
   {
       "Settings": {
           "Size": 220, 
   }
```

Post update, file content shows in a single line as follow

```
  {"Settings":{"Size":20}}
```

How can I retain the file contains spaces or indents.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to exactly maintain the original indentation, but you can instruct Json.NET to use indentation, if that's an acceptable option?

Comment: Yes, what option we have in Json.NET? Can I use it as a parameter while saving or during serialization?

Comment: A structured file like JSON or XML loses all of the formatting information when it's deserialized into in-memory objects. The only way to preserve the _exact_ formatting it originally had would be to actually store the original data from the original file. If the original is indented, you can approximate that again when writing by setting the appropriate options. See marked duplicate.

Comment: It can not be duplicated because I am not trying to write individual property and value. I have complete data ready but only issue is with indents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instruct Json.NET to indent the output by supplying "Indented" for [`Formatting`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm):

```
output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject , Formatting.Indented);
```

While this won't necessarily format the file exactly as the original, it will be output in an indented fashion.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/ZWPVDG73179)

If you need to further control how text is indented, you can create an instance of `JsonSerializer` and pass a [`JsonTextWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) to its `Serialize` method. The `JsonTextWriter` has `Indentation` (how many characters to indent by) and `IndentChar` (which character to use, e.g. `' '` for space, or `'\t'` for tab) which allow you to control the result.

Comment: Just by passing Formatting.Indented did not help, let me try JsonTextWriter suggestion. I am basically updating the appsettings.json and without indent, it's very difficult for users to use it

Comment: What do you mean `Formatting.Indented` didn't help? Are you saying you didn't get an indented file, or that it wasn't indented how you want it to be?

Comment: The file content is still in single line even after passing Formatting.Indented

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://rextester.com/ZWPVDG73179). Are you looking at the correct file?

Comment: @Jhon, I do not have backslash in my json, but you have it in your sample.

Comment: @kudlatiger That's escaping the string for C#, that's nothing to do with the JSON. Add `Console.WriteLine(json);` if you don't believe me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197847/discussion-between-kudlatiger-and-john).